# Redirect 404 Error To Another Directory

Tags: symfony, error-handling

I am using Symfony 2 framework and I am trying to re-direct my 404 page to another folder on my website. I am wondering how would I do this?

Currently, my 404 error page is located in `app/resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`. I would like my 404 page to read from `src/site/StoreBundle/Resources/views/pages/error404.html.twig`.

Note that I only want to re-direct my 404 page. I still want my other errors (500, 503) to remain in `app/resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're wanting to do this so it's difficult to advise but why can't you just put an [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) in app/resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig which pulls in your other template? Be sure to use the correct namespace for your bundle. Something like the below should be fine (edit where appropriate).

```
{% include 'StoreBundle:pages:error404.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: I like that solution. When I tried that, I get a 500 error. I'm going to try to figure out how to get an error message.

Comment: The error I get is a 404 saying it cannot find the route. I think perhaps I am using the wrong file path in include. How did you determine to use `StoreBundle:pages:error404.html.twig`?

Comment: NM. I was just using the wrong file path. Thank you. Your solution worked beautifully.